# Python Dataframe and additional column creation using ideint

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, differential-equations, odeint

Below is the dataframe and I want create col4 using odeint. Even got the equation correct but more confuse on defining value of "t" when it is dataframe. As dataframe changes depending on selection of dates

```
df.head(4)
datetime            Col1    Col2    col3    
2020-03-09 05:33:54 26.1    38.5    43.9    
2020-03-09 05:38:54 28.2    35.6    43.9
2020-03-09 05:43:54 30.3    40.7    43.9
2020-03-09 05:48:54 32.4    43.8    43.9

df['col4'] = np.NaN
df['col4'][0] = df['col3'][0] 
def model(hs,t):
    a = 0.29
    b = 15
    dhdt =  (((df['col'][0]**2)*(df['col2'][0])*a)/(b)) - (hs - df['col3'][0]);
return dhdt

for i in range(1, len(df)):
    df['col4'][i] = odeint(model,df['col4'][0],t)
```

Comment: I don't get your issue. Do you have any proble to the code running, or to understand, why it is running? or is it something else?

Comment: Problem is the output in which using odeint I create column 4 gives same value no change at all. In odeint whta is the possible value of "t" when I apply is on dataframe

Comment: setting an array element with a sequence error is the problem.. I am defining t = np.linspace(0,len(df)